# Please identify this plant

Tags: identification

I would like to find name of the plant.[image: Leaf]

Found in West Bengal , India.
Was grafted on another plant, grew thick roots.
Died after planting on soil.
[image: photos]

Comment: I’m a bit confused: You are asking about an id for the plant in the picture, which you describe as “the other plant”, right? Could you perhaps remove all details that distract from the actual question? That said, welcome to Gardening SE! As a member of the SE network, you know the basics, but a quick peek at the [help] probably won’t hurt.

Comment: thanks, much clearer. Just one tiny detail: Is this a potted plant or outdoors/wild, and if the latter, where in the world are you. For identification questions, we also have a handy little checklist [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). Thanks!